# Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My Spring Boot Project trying connect to MYSQL database with driver `mysql-connector-java`.
I have import newest mysql driver and `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I have configured database connection in `application.properties` file

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=somethingfunny
spring.datasource.password=somethingfunny
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
#spring.jpa.show-sql: true
```

MYSQL version is 8.0.26

[image]

Spring boot version 2.6.2

[image]

When run project with Intellij I get error

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
> Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory
> method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class:
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver  at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]     ... 35 common frames omitted Caused
> by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class:
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver  at
> org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:97)
> ~[spring-core-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]  at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:241)
> ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]  at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:193)
> ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]  at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:48)
> ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]  at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:90)
> ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]     ... 36 common frames omitted

I have refered the post about [Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671681/cannot-load-driver-class-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-spring-boot) (NOT com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver), I cannot apply for my project because my project get error when using `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` but not `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.

I also refered this post [Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54641439/cannot-load-driver-class-com-mysql-cj-jdbc-spring-boot). But i can not find correct answer(the answer is marked corrected) for this error.

How to fix this error ?

Comment: Check the JDK version that you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked which version of MySQL connector do you have?

Since you haven't specified the version in your pom.xml, there is a chance that it pulled version 5 and now it is complaining about that .cj which is required for version 8.

That might be the reason why is it working without .cj ( com.mysql.jdbc.Driver ), because it pulled the version 5.
Manually add the version in your pom.xml and keep .cj as it is.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.16</version>
</dependency>
```

EDIT:

This dependency from above, if you visit it in Maven central

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java

Is now moved to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.32</version>
</dependency>
```

EDIT:

After that make sure that you pull your dependencies.
But make sure that you check in your project if you do have ONLY version 8 after "mvn clean install".

As of the picture that you shared "mysql version", that means nothing, the exception is regarding mysql-connector jar, it has nothing to do with the workbench, you can still have workbench version 5, and use mysql-connector jar version 8, it will make no difference.

In any version of mysql workbench ( 5 or 8 ):

mysql-connector 8 jar = requires .cj

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

mysql-connector 5 jar = does not require .cj

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

The only thing that you need to do is define the version of mysql-connector-java in your pom.xml

Answer (score 5):

**1) Use this dependency in pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.19</version>
        </dependency>
```

**2) Use this property in your application.properties file**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Answer (score 1):

I have fix this issue. In Intellij right click to project, choose maven, choose reload project. Now Intellij will add mysql driver to the project

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Going off of one of the above answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/70514438/14111809, but with a Gradle instead of Maven (in IntelliJ IDE), this fixed the issue for me: [image: reload gradle project]

Answer (score -1):

Fix the line that sets jdbc driver class as below: I don't think it matters but driver-class-name is more common. And check if your build file is up to date. Might as well try re-building using pom.xml

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Comment: she already said "my project get error when using com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver but not com.mysql.jdbc.Driver."
I don't that that renaming the key to driver-class-name would be helpful.

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver -> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver is relevant to mysql version and I didn't say anything about that. And I did say I don't think it matters but try if it fixes it. And I did say build it again because often that fixes it. And yeah there you go. As you can see from OP's answer it was simple build-again-and-fixed kind of deal.