# Intellij "o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application run failed"

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

i tried to follow a tutorial in youtube but when i tried to run spring boot i get an error "ERROR 14272 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed".

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.5)

2023-10-22T20:43:38.068+02:00  INFO 14272 --- [           main] t.g.e.EmployeemanagerApplication         : Starting EmployeemanagerApplication using Java 17.0.7 with PID 14272 (C:\Users\haiyy\Downloads\employeemanager\employeemanager\target\classes started by haiyy in C:\Users\haiyy\Downloads\employeemanager\employeemanager)
2023-10-22T20:43:38.071+02:00  INFO 14272 --- [           main] t.g.e.EmployeemanagerApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-10-22T20:43:38.612+02:00  INFO 14272 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-10-22T20:43:38.627+02:00  INFO 14272 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 9 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-10-22T20:43:38.993+02:00  INFO 14272 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-10-22T20:43:39.000+02:00  INFO 14272 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-10-22T20:43:39.000+02:00  INFO 14272 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.15]
2023-10-22T20:43:39.084+02:00  INFO 14272 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-10-22T20:43:39.085+02:00  INFO 14272 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 977 ms
2023-10-22T20:43:39.132+02:00 ERROR 14272 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : Failed to load driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver from HikariConfig class classloader.jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1d44bcfa
2023-10-22T20:43:39.134+02:00  WARN 14272 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to load driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
2023-10-22T20:43:39.136+02:00  INFO 14272 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-10-22T20:43:39.202+02:00  INFO 14272 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-10-22T20:43:39.216+02:00 ERROR 14272 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

i tried to reinstall intellij but nothing changed

Comment: Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70504087/cannot-load-driver-class-com-mysql-cj-jdbc-driver?rq=3 Can you provide more info about your project type, eg the pom.xml or build.gradle file? Maybe tell us the link to the youtube video?